# Equivalent of GNU parallel for windows

Tags: windows, gnu-parallel

Say `myfile.txt` contains something like:

```
cd somefolder; pdflatex somefile
cd somefolder; pdflatex someotherfile
```

What is the windows equivalent of:

```
cat myfile.txt | parallel --jobs 200%
```

(which runs all commands in myfile.txt in parallel, with 2 jobs per CPU thread at the same time)

Note that the program is going to be run inside LaTeX (that forwards the command to cmd.exe as I understand it), so I’d like to avoid `wsl`, `cygwin`, `msys2`… and co.

Comment: Can you run Perl programs? GNU Parallel is 100% written in Perl, and it should be able to run on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: As Windows doesn't have `cat`, you'd probably want `parallel -a myfile.txt --jobs 200%`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, but the problem is also that windows does not have parallel (at least no trivially for what I see). I could try to install Perl and see what I can get, but I realized that xparse can easily be installed on windows, and that it provides similar parallel properties. So I guess I'll just use this from now on.